# How to force all traffic through cloudflare with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, cloudflare

I have a heroku site. How can I force all traffic through cloudflare with nodejs?

Comment: Please elaborate. Routing traffic through Cloudflare is generally involves a DNS change. Do you have a custom domain or do you use a .herakuapp.com site?

Comment: I have a custom domain

Comment: Do you have cloudflare registered and set up or partially set up at this point, if not you will need to start to follow the instructrions here: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/201720164

Comment: It is already set up. I just need to force all traffic through cloudflare with nodejs?